# How stop execution in trait php with return in Laravel

Tags: laravel, traits, laravel-9

I have the next code of my trait.

```
trait ObraTrait
{
   public function custo(Request $request)
   {
      $custo = array_sum($request->custo);

      if ($custo != 100.00) {
         return back()->withInput()->with(
            'danger','Custo equal to 100.00%'
         );
      }
   }
}
```

and my controller

```
public function update(UpdateObra $request, $id)
{
   $this->custo($request);
   ....
   return redirect()->route('app.obras.index')->with(
     'success','Obra Atualizada com Sucesso'
   );
}
```

and the answer its...

[image]

I want the controller stop when $custo != 100, that it's verified in the trait and back to the same page with a mensagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your custo() method in the trait to throw an exception when the condition is not met, and then catch that exception in your controller.

**Trait**

```
trait ObraTrait
{
    public function custo(Request $request)
    {
        $custo = array_sum($request->custo);

        if ($custo != 100.00) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Custo is not equal to 100.00%');
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(UpdateObra $request, $id)
{
    try {
        $this->custo($request);
        // Rest of your update logic...
        return redirect()->route('app.obras.index')
            ->with('success', 'Obra Atualizada com Sucesso');
    } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
        return back()->withInput()->with('danger', $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another option:

```php
trait ObraTrait
{
    public function isCusto(Request $request)
    {
        return array_sum($request->custo) != 100.00;
    }
}
```

```php
public function update(UpdateObra $request, $id)
{
   if($this->isCusto($request)) {
     return back()->withInput()->with('danger','Custo equal to 100.00%');
   }
   ....
   return redirect()->route('app.obras.index')->with(
     'success','Obra Atualizada com Sucesso'
   );
}
```

Comment: I liked this solution, but i'm gonna use the try, catch...Thanks !!!